# Facebook Webhooks Pages: Get likes and unlikes

Tags: facebook

I've set up a webhook in facebook properly and I'm receiving feed updates. So I will be notificated by adding a like, changing a comment and so on.
But when I dislike the page, there is no action send. I dont not receive anything.

I get this one, when a user adds a like:

```
{"entry": [{"changes": [{"field": "feed", "value": {"item": "like", "verb": "add"}}], "id": "216046745080249", "time": 1556272643}], "object": "page"}
```

How to determine if a user dislikes the page?? And maybe get something similar?

Comment: I don’t think that is possible.

Comment: Facebook doesn't send a message when a user "removes" his like? So I'm only able to get an upward counter?

Comment: Well apparently not, otherwise you would have gotten one … The documentation only mentions “Notifications for Page likes”, nothing about un-likes. (And I can’t really see what you would actually need that data for “in real-time” in the first place …)

Comment: I want to realise a like counter in realtime. The upward counting is working in RT.
I think its a rare case, but if I build my counter and implement in my website and some user wants to test the feature, he could like and unlike the page in a few moments.
I will be notified about the like, but not about the unlike.
My idea was to react on the notifications and read the Fan Count. So without unlike notifications I think I have to read the fan_count every XX minutes.
So if I get the point right: I would have a like counter which counts adds in realtime and removals only every XX minutes